# how to print a string in a variable based on what the user inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = '123'
#asks for input, user inputs x
#prints 123
```

how can I print a variable based on user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic variable name is not recommended, especially in this situation because you are directly taking the user input. But if you really want to implement it, `globals()` is one option:

```py
x = '123'
y = '456'

which = input('What do you want to see?: ') # x
print(globals()[which]) # 123
```

A better and more secure approach would be to use a dict:

```py
user_vars = {'x': '123', 'y': '456'}

which = input('What do you want to see?: ') # x
print(user_vars[which]) # 123
```

Answer (score 2):

`input()` can be used to fetch input from the command line.

```py
name = input("Your Name: ")
print("Hello there, " + name + "!")
```

Comment: yes, but not what I'm trying to solve, this will print the input I enter.
I have a variables let's say 
x = 'one'
I want to take input,  user inputs x
and then the script prints the string inside the x variable

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the dictionary in python as follows:

```
user_options = {'x': '123', 'y': '456', 'z': '789'}

entered_value = input('Please enter an input?: ') # could be x, y or z depending upon the dictionary
print(user_options[entered_value])
```

This should give you the number depending on if x,y, or z is entered

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `eval()`,

The `eval()` method parses the expression passed to this method and runs python expression (code) within the program.

```
x = '123'
try:
    print(eval(input()))
except NameError:
    print("Invalid variable name")
```